# Retrieve selected choices from Django form ChoiceField

Tags: django

I'm attempting to make a search functionality on my Django web app. The idea is that users will go to the front page and be able to select from a drop down list of properties (ie. the OS, compiler, etc) and then submit their search which should return a list of matching builds.  I have the ChoiceField form set up and I know the code I need to run to get the proper build in my next view. What I don't know is how to pass the values the user selected when they hit submit to the next view so I can filter based on those choices.  Any help?

**forms.py**

```
from .models import * 

class BuildForm(forms.Form):
    build_OPTIONS = Builds.objects.values().distinct()
    ...
    Build_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=build_OPTIONS)
```

**views.py**

```
from .forms import BuildForm

def index(request):
    builds = BuildForm()
    return render(request, 'ReportGenerator/index.html', 
{"builds":builds})
```

**templates/App/index.html**

```
{% if builds %}
     <h2>Pick a Build</h2>
     <form method="POST" class="build-form">{% csrf_token %}
       {{ builds.as_p }}
     </form>
{% else %}
    <p>No reports are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your build_OPTIONS that you use as choices, it would probably be best to define them inside the model like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#choices).  And then you can reference them in your form class like so:

**models.py**

```
class Builds(models.Model):
    CHOICE1 = "Choice 1"
    CHOICE2 = "Choice 2"
    BUILD_OPTIONS_CHOICES = (
        (CHOICE1, 'Choice 1'),
        (CHOICE2, 'Choice 2'),
        (<value>, <human readable name>),
    )
    ...fields...
```

**forms.py**

```
from .models import * 

class BuildForm(forms.Form):
    ...
    Build_type = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(), choices=Builds.BUILD_OPTIONS_CHOICES)
```

Here's an example for the view.  If `form.is_valid()` returns `True` then you can access the form values in `form.cleaned_data['my_form_field_name']`

**views.py**

```
def index(request):
    # if this is a POST request we need to process the form data
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # create a form instance and populate it with data from the request:
        form = BuildForm(request.POST)
        # check whether it's valid:
        if form.is_valid():
            # can access the form data in cleaned_data['form_field_name']
            print form.cleaned_data['build_type'] 

            # redirect to a new URL:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        form = BuildForm()

    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

As for the form field name, it's probably build_options and build_type.  Usually it uses whatever the variable name is in the form class.  To make life easier, I would standardize on all lowercase characters with underscores for the variable names, capitalized first letters for class names, all uppercase for constants, etc.  For more information see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates) page where it describes how `as_p()` works.